# Static file not loading via wwwroot c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

Ok so I don't know what I am missing here. All I am trying to do is show that my static css file is linking to my index page. I have loaded the dependencies  and have it in the startup.cs  was hoping someone could tell me where Im messing it up. ALl this should do is turn the h1 in index green  The page does load just fine just not changing the color.

```
Project.json

"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",


Startup.cs

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory 
loggerFactory)
        {
            // Use the Mvc to handle Http requests and responses

            loggerFactory.AddConsole();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

Index.cshtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "test">
            <h1>Hello ASP.NET Mvc!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Style.css

*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

h1{
    color: green;
}



    Structure of wwwroot

    wwwroot
       css
         style.css
```

Comment: Have you investigated enabling static content via IIS settings?

Comment: Yea Im in school learning all this and Following all the stuff and even resarched microsoft I seem to have it setup right thinking I got something stupid broken

Comment: Can you browse to /css/style.css?

Comment: No i cannot i tired

Answer (score 0):

Read this to enable static content:
[link](https://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation)

Comment: I checked it but was on already i cleaned out and reinstalled it but no luck ty

Comment: And you are sure the css is in your project and in that path?  Can you see it in IIS when you view content?  You may also try using a relative path ("href="../css/style.css")